# How to replace a placeholder string stored in an object/array property in a Drupal Twig template with the current year?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a custom block which returns an array with a text-field.

How can I replace the string `%current_year%` in the `#text` property of the array with the current year in my twig template?

```
'0' => array(4)
   '#type' => string(14) "processed_text"
   '#text' => string UTF-8(119) "The current year is %current_year%."
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the string inside the array (data-manipulation) or do you want to render the text/string with the placeholder replaced on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your array/object is passed to the template as the variable `myObject`.

You can render the string in the `#text` property while replacing the placeholder as follows:

```
{{ attribute(myObject, '#text') | replace({"%current_year%": ("now"|date("Y"))}) }}
```

... or use an intermediate variable ...

```
{% set currentYear = "now"|date("Y") %}
{{ attribute(myObject, '#text') | replace({"%current_year%": currentYear}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do it in a such way, but faced a problem with rendering, sorry, I didn't mention, that I have html tags in this property, so how to render it like html, not a string?

Comment: Just use the `raw` filter additionally to prevent twig from auto-escaping the string i.e. `{{ myString | raw }}`